# How would I set the variable distance for an object on an addClass within JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive, scrollto

How would I set the distance to a specific section on the screen instead of using pixels for distance and the responsiveness of my layout changes where the css animation happens when the class is added.

```
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  var distance = 570;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > distance) {
  $('.fa-left-inner').addClass('expand-inner-left');
```

Working code would be great, however the knowledge to understand and replicate in the future would be priceless. Thank you for your help.

Comment: please edit your title in some way when someone have a problem similar to yours to reach this page

Comment: media queries don't help to you? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it's fairly unclear what you're asking and what you want help with

Comment: @gforce301 I have edited the title and cleaned up the content hoping that this would make it more clear. Please let me know if it's still difficult

Comment: @CalvinNunes I need the distance to be a set place on the place in JS not a pixel length. CSS media queries are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @BoteaFlorin Done, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @SamHollis First this is not a verifiable example. I can't run that code and see the problem. Second, what do you mean by "set the distance to a specific section on the screen instead of using pixels for distance "? In what other way do you wish to measure distance in a browser, since they use pixels as their unit of measurement? Third, what is it that you are really trying to do? This seems very much like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do yo uneed to measure this "distance"? What effect are you really trying to achieve?